shorten a wavy connection (snake decoration)
To draw wavy bonds, the chemfig documentation suggests using the snake decoration.
I would like to be able to shorten this bond because I find it unsightly compared to the others

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %pour ajouter des liaisons ondulées dans chemfig

\begin{document}


\chemfig{-[:-30](-[:210])-[,3,,,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length =5mm}]}
\end{document}


The optional argument for chemfig chemical bonds has the syntax:
[<angle>,<length>,<atom 1>,<atom 2>,<extra tikz code>]

Here replace 3 by the desired value, or let it empty.
Example:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %pour ajouter des liaisons ondulées dans chemfig

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  -[:-30](-[:210])-[,,,,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length =5mm}]
}

\end{document}


